# C++ Socket Error (new initializer expression list treated as compound expression)

Tags: c++, sockets

i'm starting coding socket in c++ and i have a strange error :

```
C:\Users\Martin\CLionProjects\CryptoRecv\connexion.cpp:11:56: error: new initializer expression list treated as compound expression [-fpermissive]
 sock = new SOCKET(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
```

The code :

```
connexion::connexion(std::string ip, int port) {
WSADATA WSAData;
WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &WSAData);
sock = new SOCKET(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP); /*<--- Error ligne*/
if(*sock == INVALID_SOCKET){
    std::cout << "INVALID SOCKET" << std::endl;
}

addr = new SOCKADDR_IN;
addr->sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip.data());
addr->sin_family = AF_INET;
addr->sin_port = htonl(port);

if(connect(*sock, (SOCKADDR *)addr, sizeof(*addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    std::cout << "Erreur connection : " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
}

message = new std::string();
}
```

This code work well before i put it in a class.
Sorry for bad english.
:)

Comment: That's not line 11.

Comment: There are some ligne before but it's just the header include and comment. The error line is indicate.

Comment: Well, the headers would probably show what `SOCKET` is.

Comment: Header : https://ghostbin.com/paste/opb75

Comment: Don't post references to external sources. Include them here.

Comment: `SOCKET`, on my system, is defined as `typedef UINT_PTR SOCKET;`, while `UINT_PTR` is defined as `typedef _W64 unsigned int UINT_PTR, *PUINT_PTR;`. Do you think that `unsigned int` has a constructor, that accepts 3 arguments? Did you want to call [WSASocket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms742212(v=vs.85).aspx) instead?

Comment: Why are you trying to dynamically allocate an integer (`SOCKET`) and a `std::string`?

Comment: It's bad to allocate dynamically SOCKET and std::string ?

Comment: I'm using windows socket indeed but SOCKET with 3 arguments work well on my system before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just from reading the code, I think your problem should be solved by changing the line that have caused the error with this one :

```
sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
```

socket() is a function and not a class to try to instantiate it.

Make sure that you have already declared "sock" variable as an instance in your class, because I don't see it in your function.